# Css for popup kendo grid is corrupted on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added those to my rezor view

```
"kendo.common.min.css" 
"kendo.default.min.css"
"kendo.rtl.min.css"
```

and one script for culture
here it is on Chrome
 [image]

and on fire fox it's ok

[image]

Can  you please suggest any thing do solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing some what the same problem.

Its work fine when i updated kendo.web.min.js and kendo.common.min.css file.

May be you should update kendo package to latest version and have a test.